# Git crashing on WinSSHFS network drive

Tags: git

Due to bash dependencies in the project I work on it's running inside a virtual machine with the code mounted as a virtual drive using WinSSHFS. This works nicely, however for some reason `git` simply crashes if I try to run virtually anything except `git help`. I have tried various git executable I could find online, but as far as I can tell they are all the same one ( git-scm.com ).

Git doesn't seem to log anything, and nothing is outputted to the console, so I am at a loss where to look even. Everything works perfectly fine from inside the virtual machine, however I really appreciate the integration in my IDE. Any ideas on how to approach this problem or inspect the git crashes would be greatly appreciated.